# KDE Menu Editor: why inverted commas that are absent in the launcher file?

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, launcher

I have created the file `~/.local/share/applications/software-properties-qt.desktop` with the line `Exec=pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true software-properties-qt`, which works just fine. But the KDE Menu Editor or the Application Launcher right-click menu option "Edit Application" show parts of the command with inverted commas:

```
env 'DISPLAY=$DISPLAY' 'XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY' KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5 KDE_FULL_SESSION=true software-properties-qt
```

[image]

Why is that?